# Get data-* value of parent of clicked child

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following list element

```
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"><span class="product_name" style="font-size:24px; color:#870FD1" data-price= "121.34"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></span> Bleed Hydraulic brake system - ABS <span class="product_name"><u>More info</u></span></li>
```

and i want to read `data-price= "121.34"` and this text `Bleed Hydraulic brake system - ABS`

I have set the clicked element as `<i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>` and so far i cant read the data attribute value of the parent

```
$(".bi-plus-circle").click(function(){
     alert($('.bi-plus-circle').parent().attr('price'));
      });
```

I have several `<li></li>` elements and this too doesn't get me the data i want

```
$(".bi-plus-circle").click(function(){
     alert($(this).parent().attr('price'));
});
```

How can read the price and the product text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)() method from jquery instead of attr()

```css
$(".bi-plus-circle").click(function(){
     console.log($('.bi-plus-circle').parent().data("price"));
});
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <span class="product_name" style="font-size:24px; color:#870FD1" data-price= "121.34">
    <i class="bi bi-plus-circle">(+)</i>
  </span>
  Bleed Hydraulic brake system - ABS
  <span class="product_name"><u>More info</u></span>
</li>
```

Comment: How about this text "  Bleed Hydraulic brake system - ABS"

Comment: `$('.bi-plus-circle').parent()[0].nextSibling.textContent` , but this is coupled extremely close with the mark-up. If you have access to the HTML, I’d suggest wrapping the text in another element with a succinct class name.